# Which of the following implementations should I use for tag dispatching? Why?

Tags: c++, templates

I am wondering which of the two following two versions should I use for tag dispatching. I have got this situation in a project and I would like to use the best solution. The implementations in the standard use the first solution, but I would like to know why and the implications in efficiency if there are some.

```
struct tag1{};
struct tag2{};

struct A{
    using tag = tag1;
};

struct B{
    using tag = tag2;
};

template<typename Tag>
struct Dispatcher;

template<typename T>
void dispatch(T a){
    dispatch(a, T::tag()); ////// Solution 1
    Dispatcher<typename T::tag>::dispatch(a); //////Solution 2
}
```

First solution:

```
/////////////////Solution 1///////////////////
template<typename T>
void dispatch(T a, tag1){
    std::cout << "tag1 selected" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void dispatch(T a, tag2){
    std::cout << "tag2 selected" << std::endl;
}
/////////////////Solution 1///////////////////
```

Second solution:

```
/////////////////Solution 2///////////////////
template<>
struct Dispatcher<tag1>{
    template<typename T>
    static void dispatch(T a){
        std::cout << "tag1 selected" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct Dispatcher<tag2>{
    template<typename T>
    static void dispatch(T a){
        std::cout << "tag2 selected" << std::endl;
    }
};
/////////////////Solution 2///////////////////
```

Comment: Technically, the second is no tag dispatching (See: http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php#tag_dispatching)

Comment: And some `typename`s to access `T`'s dependent type `tag` :)

Comment: Note: Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope is not allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the question from the wrong place, I just edited and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first.  That's actually tag dispatching and the other is not.  The reason being is that tag dispatching uses function overloading rules to decide what to call.  Tags can inherit from each other allowing you to create functions that operate at very concrete or very abstract levels.

Your second technique is useful in many situations.  See how it's used in places like boost.fusion and boost.mpl.  It's not tag dispatching though, so if you know you want tag dispatching to solve your problem then you're using the first technique, not the second.

As to which you should actually use to solve your particular problem--not knowing what it is I can't say.

Edit: In the MPL for example it's used to create generic operations and allow you a path to override.  So for like the begin<> metafunction there's a begin_impl or begin_traits you implement (don't recall the name, look it up) for your own sequence types like so:

```
struct my_sequence_tag {};

namespace boost { namespace mpl {
    template < >
    struct begin_impl<my_sequence_tag>
    {
        template < typename Sequence >
        struct apply { /* ... */ };

    };
}}
```

Boost's begin<> metafunction is then implemented something like so:

```
template < typename Sequence >
struct begin
    : begin_impl<typename Sequence::tag>::template apply<Sequence>
{};
```